# Admob: where does adview xml come from?

Tags: android, admob

I have followed a few tutorials / stackoverflow threads to learn how to add an `Admob` banner to the bottom of my UI.

I have added the adMob sdk to the lib, added the following to the XML for the UI that I want to show the ad on

```
<RelativeLayout 
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
      xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"     
      android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
      android:background="#000000">      


<com.google.ads.AdView 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:id="@+id/adMob"
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
  ads:adUnitId="YOUR AdMob publisher ID"
  ads:adSize="BANNER"/>
```

I then add the following to my java code for this UI

```
AdView adview = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);  
AdRequest re = new AdRequest();  
re.setTesting(true);  
adview.loadAd(re);
```

The problem I have is that I have no xml called `"adView"`. I've tried a few different versions of the Java code (each tutorial is a bit different) but all result in a similar java error. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't got any `R.id.adView` (at least in the code you paste), you have to use `R.id.adMob`, because this is the view's ID.
You have to add this to your Layout file:

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing Admob library that contains adView.please add that.

[Here](http://blog.kerul.net/2012/08/example-how-to-install-google-admob-6x.html) is the complete tutorial how to add Admob to your app.

hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using productFlavors in build.gradle make sure you add the 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.5.0' dependency in the productFlavors block not the generic dependency block.

```
 productFlavors {
      free {
          ...
          dependencies {
              compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.5.0'
          }
      }

      full {
          ...
      }
    }
```